# no password provided rails 6 with RAILS_ENV=production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, passenger-nginx

i try to put my rails api into digital oceans server with nginx and passenger, so far i got it working but when i try to send a request with postman to my server i have a 500 internal error after checking log/production.log, the 500 internal error is due to `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (fe_sendauth: no password supplied`
This is weird because `RAILS_ENV=production rails db:setup` is working,i have my master.key for credentials and secret_key_base is in it, environnement variable in my bashrc for username database and password database. when i do `RAILS_ENV=production rails c` i can see my `ENV["MYAPP_DATABASE_USER"]`
still in my rails console in production mode i can do `Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base` she is there !

postgres user is set correctly with the same password i supply to rails.. maybe its passenger who is not working properly... but i don't know how to properly check it.

**EDIT : PROBLEM SOLVE**

i was able to solve my problem passing my env variable to nginx like this
in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.conf`

```
passenger_env_var KEY VALUE;
```

passenger doc's say that he is reading the bashrc file for env variable ... but its ok like that hope its help some dude over here hehe ;)

Comment: Have you entered in nginx settings that env is `production` ?

Comment: ```
passenger_enabled on;
passenger_app_env production;
```
in server block